# Upgrading PHP 5.2.17 to 5.3

Tags: php

Our server currently runs PHP installed as CGI in Apache on Cent-OS.

What are the advantages/possible problems with upgrading from 5.2.17 to 5.3? My dedi host says that it will most likely break my sites, but hasn't given any actual things that could break.

Our server is 98% WordPress with a bunch of custom functionality. Where can I find a list of deprecated/changed functions, changed format, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with the statement that an upgrade will "most likely" break your sites, but it is a very strong possibility.

Generally speaking, code that worked on PHP 5.2 will work on 5.3. And while I can't speak for any custom code, as far as Wordpress is concerned you should be on the latest stable version.

A list of changes can be found at: 
http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php

Comment: What are the benefits of upgrading?

Comment: @KorvinSzanto None, if you don't miss a feature. If you miss one, then this is the benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is too short, but what should I say?! It took me 3 seconds of Google.

http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php

Comment: Also, see http://php.net/migration53 which details the points of interest for users upgrading from 5.2 to 5.3.

Comment: Which is directly linked from within the provided link. There is other useful information in it. Read it.